# ngdialog watch function not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, ng-dialog

I put plugin in my screen. With in popup I put search box but watch function not working for search box. If I put search box out of popup, by that time watch working. With in popup watch function not working. What can I do?

> ngDialog

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="userDialogId">
        <input type="text" class="text-box" ng-model="searchUsersonly" ng-change="searchUserbyChange" placeholder="Search users">
    {{counted}}
```

```
$scope.counted
$scope.$watch("searchUsersonly", function(query){
    $scope.counted++
});
```

> http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDialog

Answer (score -1):

Put one inside controller then working fine